# Question about different definitions of isometry on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\mathcal{H} , (\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space over the field $\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (so the norm on $\mathcal{H}$ is given by $\|\cdot\| = (\cdot, \cdot)^{\frac{1}{2}}$). If $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is a bounded linear operator, I have seen two different definitions for what it means for $T$ to be an **isometry**:

1. $T$ isometric $\iff \|x\| = \|Tx\|$, all $x \in H$ (from page 197 of Reed and Simon's [*Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Vol. 1*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics_F.html?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C)).
2. $T$ isometric $\iff (x,y) = (Tx,Ty)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$ (from [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Isometry_(Hilbert_Spaces)) ProofWiki page on isometry).

It is clear that $2 \implies 1$, and in the case $\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{C}$, we have $1 \implies 2$ by the polarization identity:

$$(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}((\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2) - i(\|x + iy\|^2 - \|x - iy\|^2)).$$

> My question is, are the definitions equivalent when $\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{R}$? Because in that case, we don't have the polarization identity at our disposal.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, there is a real version of the polarization identity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_real_scalars

Comment: @copper.hat - Wow! Thank you for the reference. For some reason I thought there was only a polarization identity in the complex case. This will help me with many things.

Comment: In the real case you also have $\langle x, y \rangle = {1 \over 2} \left( \|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2 \right)$.

Comment: It's kind of strange you've not heard of the real polarisation identity. I always found it way more intuitive and natural than the complex one (I always have hard time deriving that when I need it).

Comment: Assume $A$ is linear. The problem you get into on real spaces is that $(Ax,x)=0$ for all $x$ does not imply $A=0$. This cannot happen for complex spaces. For complex spaces this implies $(Ax,y)=0$ for all $x$, $y$, which forces $A=0$. But using real polarization, you can't get beyond $(Ax,y)+(x,Ay)=0$, which means $A$ is anti-symmetric. If you know that $A$ is symmetric, then it is true that $A=0$ if $(Ax,x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the first comment above: the answer is yes. The definitions are equivalent, even in the case $\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{R}$. This is because there is also a real version of the polarization identity:

$$(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2 - ||x-y||^2).$$